# How to translate "dropped my heart"?

Tags: phrase-request, idioms

There's a phrase in Thai, ตกใจหมดเลย `[tòk-tɕɑi-mòt-lɤːi]`, which means "to be frightened", as if someone suddenly broke a glass on a floor behind your back.

Literally, it can be translated "dropped-heart-depleted-completely" (don't try [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#th/en/%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%88%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%94%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%A2); it's wrong).

Surprisingly enough, I understood it intuitively because there's a Russian idiom "душа ушла в пятки" ("soul went to {one's} heels").
Both Thai and Russian idioms hold a certain amount of humorous context.

I was trying to translate it to English, but only found ["frightened to death"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scared) which does not look humorous at all. **Is there a better phrase to denote being frightened, with considerations above?**

Comment: I would try _scared the crap out of me_. There are [other versions](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You+scared+the+crap+out+of+me) (some more vulgar) as well.

Comment: *My heart skipped a beat*. *My heart stopped.*  *My heart dropped*, however, means *I was abruptly saddened*.

Comment: @StoneyB: Except *my heart **sank*** is probably 10-20 times more common than *dropped* for the "saddened" sense.

Comment: There's an idiom about one's heart leaping into one's mouth (different from Wordsworth's _[My heart leaps up when I behold a rainbow in the sky](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/my-heart-leaps-up/)). This [signifies fear](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/heart+in+one's+mouth,+have+one's), not sadness.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, indeed; it occurs in the same ratio to  *my heart fell*. I cited the *dropped* one because it's close to OP's original.

Comment: [*You scared the (living) daylights out of me*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scare-the-living-daylights-out-of-someone)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If  you're looking for something humorous, then you'll have to create your own translation, in the spirit of [Arthur Waley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Waley), the great American translator of poetry from Chinese and Japanese to English. Waley was criticized, unjustly, IMHO, for his brilliant translation of *[The Tale of Genji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genji_Monogatari)* by a contemporary translator, [Edward Seidensticker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Seidensticker), touted as "the best translator of Japanese that has ever lived", but, frankly, I found his "faithful to the original text" translation an utter bore compared with Waley's. Waley was a poet; Seidensticker was a translator. There's a world of difference.

Enough background. I'm suggesting that you create your own phrase. I'm not a poet, but I do have a suggestion. Why not say something on the order of "my heart dropped down my leg and into my shoe, rolled between my toes, then stopped for a full five seconds until I caught my breath again"? You can change things to say what **you** think will amuse your readers or listeners. Everything else that's been suggested here, including my earlier suggestion of "my heart lept into my mouth", is merely a cliché. Avoid clichés whenever possible.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it goes farther than I asked. In fact, it answers most further questions about translating idiomatic constructs. I must admit, however, that following your answer might be difficult for an average language learner. :)

Comment: @bytebuster: You're a polyglot (Thai, Russian, English, ??) & hardly an average language learner. I wrote that especially for you because I know you can do it. A good teacher has to be able to assess the capabilities of students. I've been teaching English & writing for 40 years. Some people have said that I'm a good teacher. Sometimes that's true. Thank you for accepting the answer. I'm happy that it's useful. That's my goal here, to be useful to EFL students.

Answer (score 6):

I'll post StoneyB's

> *My heart skipped a beat.*

as a community wiki answer. I don't see the point of inviting a potentially limitless set of alternative phrasings not involving the word "heart", but if anyone wants to add to the list, here's one to start...

> *I nearly shat myself*.
>   *Thunderstruck.*

Comment: I love how you picked *that one* to start

Comment: @Deco: Well, I thought it had a certain "lightness" on account of the somewhat vague status of "shat" as a past tense, and OP wanted a bit of humour. But it's just occurred to me it mightn't be suitable for all contexts/audiences. On the other hand, you could probably get away with *"I almost wet myself"* just about anywhere. Go on! Indulge yourself! Edit that (or something else) into the answer! That's why I made it wiki, after all.

Comment: _almost wet oneself_ sounds a good idiomatic expression, but isn't it derogatory in a Western culture? (no problem for Thai culture, however)

Comment: I think that's at least the second time you've used *derogatory* in an unusual way here on ELL. It's *very, very slightly* "rude, indelicate, risqué, unseemly", as are all metaphorical references to bodily functions. But *derogatory* means *insulting towards a person* - if I said "You are stupid", that's "derogatory". If I say "I am a twat", it's self-deprecating - but because I'm talking about myself, most people wouldn't say I was being derogatory.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I forgot the `:)` in my comment, it made me smile when I read it is all

Answer (score 4):

I think

> "My heart was in my mouth."

Is the closet you'll get in English. If you're looking for a humerous way to describe fright, I think

> Scared stiff

and

> Scared shitless

are pretty good. Scared shitless is vulgar, though.

Comment: Having one's heart in one's mouth is more an anticipation-scared than scared because someone/something made you jump, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure that avoidance of cliches is necessary. I'm not Thai and so it's not clear that the original phrase was not also a cliche to Thai speakers. There are English expressions (referring to the heart):

> My heart jumped out of my chest.

> My heart stopped. (Although I see it was in the comments.)

> My heart was pounding.

For expressions of surprise there're also:

> Jumped out of my shoes.

> Scared the wits out of me.