# English version of a Cuban expression

Tags: phrase-request

There is a Cuban phrase that means - literally- I HAVE MONEY EVEN TO MAKE DESSERT WITH IT, or something like that. I guess it's like having too much of something. Is there an English expression for this?

Comment: Hi Esteban Alvarez. I have edited the question, as asking for a "translation" didn't seem accurate. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Esteban: I don't really understand how that Cuban phrase works. Do you mean "dessert" as in *sweet course / pudding / afters*? I can't see how you could *literally* use money to make something nice to eat. Is there something "lost in translation" there?

Comment: I think he means it's a literal translation.

Comment: @nxx: I know *that!* (OP says so). I'm asking how it can work in the (Spanish?) original, since I can't see any semantic connection between money and *even* having enough to make dessert (with it?).

Comment: http://www.pinterest.com/pin/42010208997768818/

Comment: A sheer guess would be something along the lines of "money to burn", but we would need more context to figure that out. Esteban, see http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/2725/748 for another example of asking for a phrase translation. It may give you some ideas for how to better frame your question.

Answer (score 4):

It's not *completely* clear to me what exactly OP's Cuban phrase is supposed to mean, but I'm going to hazard a guess and say it might be the equivalent of the common English phrase...

> *He's got [money to burn](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/have-money-to-burn)*

Cambridge Dictionaries define this in that link as *to spend a lot of money on things that are not necessary*, but I think that implication of actually *spending* money doesn't need to be present. It might be possible to say, for example,

> *He's so mean he won't even tip the postman at Christmas, but I know he's got money to burn.*

(i.e. - it can just mean he has *a lot of money*, even if he doesn't often spend much)

---

In case it's not obvious, the figurative allusion is to the idea that one could be so rich he didn't even care about using money to buy coal for the fire - he could just burn banknotes to keep warm. It's the same idea in this stereotypical image of an ostentatiously wealthy man...
[image]

---

As @nxx's answer suggests, there are a very large number of idiomatic expressions in English for *having enough/a lot/too much* of something - most of which can be used for a wide range of different (good, bad, or neutral) things. As *money to burn* is so common, "creative variations" do sometimes occur...

> I only smoke after sex, but I bought my full duty-free allowance when I came back from holiday abroad last month, so I've got cigarettes to burn.

...but such "extensions" are rare, and *very* rarely used of anything that couldn't be *literally* burned.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of English expressions that I think are appropriate:

**to have "[something coming out of your ears](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/have-sth-coming-out-of-your-ears)"**,

which means

> to have more of something than you want or need

eg, *I have money coming out (of) my ears.*

**to have something "[in spades](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+spades)"**:

> in large amounts or to a very great degree

eg, *I have money in spades.*

**to have "more than I can [shake a stick at](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/more-than-you-can-shake-a-stick-at)"**

> a lot of

eg, *I have more money than I can shake a stick at.*

These can all be used for things other than money, too, and all imply having an [excess](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excess). So you are lucky if these apply to you!